# Kafka UNKNOWN_PRODUCER_ID exception

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I sometimes find `UNKNOWN_PRODUCER_ID` exception when using kafka streams.

```
2018-06-25 10:31:38.329  WARN 1 --- [-1-1_0-producer] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=default-groupz-7bd94946-3bc0-4400-8e73-7126b9b9c0d4-StreamThread-1-1_0-producer, transactionalId=default-groupz-1_0] Got error produce response with correlation id 1996 on topic-partition default-groupz-mplat-five-minute-stat-urlCount-counts-store-changelog-0, retrying (2147483646 attempts left). Error: UNKNOWN_PRODUCER_ID
```

Referred to official documents:

> This exception is raised by the broker if it could not locate the
>   producer metadata associated with the producerId in question. This
>   could happen if, for instance, the producer's records were deleted
>   because their retention time had elapsed. Once the last records of the
>   producerId are removed, the producer's metadata is removed from the
>   broker, and future appends by the producer will return this exception.

It says one possibility is that a producer is idle for more than retention time (by default a week) so the producer's metadata will be removed from broker. Are there any other reasons that brokers could not locate producer metadata?

Answer (score 4):

You might be experiencing https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7190. As it says in that ticket:

> When a streams application has little traffic, then it is possible that consumer purging would delete
>   even the last message sent by a producer (i.e., all the messages sent by
>   this producer have been consumed and committed), and as a result, the broker
>   would delete that producer's ID. The next time when this producer tries to
>   send, it will get this UNKNOWN_PRODUCER_ID error code, but in this case,
>   this error is retriable: the producer would just get a new producer id and
>   retries, and then this time it will succeed.

This issue is also being tracked at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-360%3A+Improve+handling+of+unknown+producer

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons might delete your producer's metadata:

1. The log segments are deleted due to hitting retention time.
2. The producer state might get expired due to inactivity which is controlled by the setting **transactional.id.expiration.ms** which defaults to 7 days

So if your Kafka is < 2.4 you can workaround this by increasing the retention time(considering that your system allows that) of your topic's log(e.g 30 days) and to increase the **transactional.id.expiration.ms** setting( to 24 days) until [KIP-360](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-360%3A+Improve+handling+of+unknown+producer) is released:

> log.retention.hours=720
>
> transactional.id.expiration.ms=2073600000

This shall guarantee that for low-traffic topics(messages written rarely than 7 days), your producer's metadata state will remain stored in broker's memory for a longer period, thus decreasing the risk of getting UnknownProducerIdException.