# How to handle UnkownProducerIdException

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-kafka

We are having some troubles with Spring Cloud and Kafka, at sometimes our microservice throws an `UnkownProducerIdException`, this is caused if the parameter `transactional.id.expiration.ms` is expired in the broker side.

My question, could it be possible to catch that exception and retry the failed message? If yes, what could be the best option to handle it?

I have took a look at:
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=89068820
- [Kafka UNKNOWN_PRODUCER_ID exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036351/kafka-unknown-producer-id-exception)

We are using Spring Cloud `Hoxton.RELEASE` version and Spring Kafka version `2.2.4.RELEASE`

We are using AWS Kafka solution so we can't set a new value on that property I mentioned before.

Here is some trace of the exception:

```
2020-04-07 20:54:00.563 ERROR 5188 --- [ad | producer-2] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-2] The broker returned org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownProducerIdException: This exception is raised by the broker if it could not locate the producer metadata associated with the producerId in question. This could happen if, for instance, the producer's records were deleted because their retention time had elapsed. Once the last records of the producerId are removed, the producer's metadata is removed from the broker, and future appends by the producer will return this exception. for topic-partition test.produce.another-2 with producerId 35000, epoch 0, and sequence number 8
2020-04-07 20:54:00.563  INFO 5188 --- [ad | producer-2] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-2] ProducerId set to -1 with epoch -1
2020-04-07 20:54:00.565 ERROR 5188 --- [ad | producer-2] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='{...}' to topic <some-topic>:
```

To reproduce this exception:
- I have used the [confluent docker images](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/5.3.1-post/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml) and set the environment variable `KAFKA_TRANSACTIONAL_ID_EXPIRATION_MS` to 10 seconds so I wouldn't wait too much for this exception to be thrown.
- In another process, send one by one in interval of 10 seconds 1 message in the topic the java will listen.

Here is a code example:

File **Bindings.java**

```java
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Output;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel;

public interface Bindings {
  @Input("test-input")
  SubscribableChannel testListener();

  @Output("test-output")
  MessageChannel testProducer();
}
```

File **application.yml** (don't forget to set the environment variable `KAFKA_HOST`):

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          auto-create-topics: true
          brokers: ${KAFKA_HOST}
          transaction:
            producer:
              error-channel-enabled: true
          producer-properties:
            acks: all
            retry.backoff.ms: 200
            linger.ms: 100
            max.in.flight.requests.per.connection: 1
            enable.idempotence: true
            retries: 3
            compression.type: snappy
            request.timeout.ms: 5000
            key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
          consumer-properties:
            session.timeout.ms: 20000
            max.poll.interval.ms: 350000
            enable.auto.commit: true
            allow.auto.create.topics: true
            auto.commit.interval.ms: 12000
            max.poll.records: 5
            isolation.level: read_committed
          configuration:
            auto.offset.reset: latest

      bindings:

        test-input:
          # contentType: text/plain
          destination: test.produce
          group: group-input
          consumer:
            maxAttempts: 3
            startOffset: latest
            autoCommitOnError: true
            queueBufferingMaxMessages: 100000
            autoCommitOffset: true


        test-output:
          # contentType: text/plain
          destination: test.produce.another
          group: group-output
          producer:
            acks: all

debug: true
```

The listener handler:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Bindings.class)
public class PocApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PocApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PocApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Autowired
    private BinderAwareChannelResolver binderAwareChannelResolver;

    @StreamListener(Topics.TESTLISTENINPUT)
    public void listen(Message<?> in, String headerKey) {
        final MessageBuilder builder;
        MessageChannel messageChannel;

        messageChannel = this.binderAwareChannelResolver.resolveDestination("test-output");

        Object payload = in.getPayload();
        builder = MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload);

        try {
            log.info("Event received: {}", in);

            if (!messageChannel.send(builder.build())) {
                log.error("Something happend trying send the message! {}", in.getPayload());
            }

            log.info("Commit success");
        } catch (UnknownProducerIdException e) {
            log.error("UnkownProducerIdException catched ", e);
        } catch (KafkaException e) {
            log.error("KafkaException catched ", e);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Commit failed " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Can you edit the question to show a full stack trace?

Comment: Sure! I have added it @GaryRussell

Comment: I am having trouble reproducing it; can you show how you are sending? That said, the exception is coming back on another thread so you need to either add a listener to the future or calling `get(time, unit)` to get the result of the send.

Comment: I will update it with an example tomorrow. I am using the `MessageChannel` interface and bindings. 
How can I add that listener you are talking? Is there an example so I can use it? Thank you so much

Comment: It's a bit more complicated when using Spring Cloud Stream (if that's what you mean). I'll wait to see your code.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell I have updated the issue with an example. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        } catch (UnknownProducerIdException e) {
            log.error("UnkownProducerIdException catched ", e);
```

To catch exceptions there, you need to set the `sync` kafka producer property (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-producer-properties). Otherwise, the error comes back asynchronously

You should not "eat" the exception there; it must be thrown back to the container so the container will roll back the transaction.

Also,

```
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Commit failed " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

The commit is performed by the container after the stream listener returns to the container so you will never see a commit error here; again, you must let the exception propagate back to the container.

The container will retry the delivery according to the consumer binding's retry configuration.

Comment: Hi Gary, thank you so much for the answer. We tried the `sync` option before in the `producer` config but still we couldn't catch the exception.
When you say "thrown back to the container" what did you mean there?

Comment: If you are using transactions, the sync needs to go on the transactional producer configuration.

Comment: Sure, but we are not using transactions here. Also it is not enabled the transactionality

Comment: I am confused; you said you were forcing `UnkownProducerIdException` by using transaction expiration.

Comment: As I said, I need to know how to reproduce the `UnkownProducerIdException` so I can figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, that's right, we are using AWS kafka solution and it has a retention metadata for 7 days, when the producer tries to send a message in kafka the client throws that error. I have tried to reproduce it in my local machine to debug it.

Comment: If you mean you might have a producer sit for more than 7 days without sending anything, one thing you could do is call `reset()` on the producer factory, say, once a day. The problem is, Spring Cloud Stream doesn't provide a mehanism to expose the producer factory. I suggest you open an issue against the kafka binder on GitHub. There is a hack you can use to get a reference to it using reflection which I can add, if you want.

Comment: Ok we will try that. I have created a gist page with the essential code to reproduce it. You will need a script to produce in the topic inside the `application.yaml` https://gist.github.com/ervitis/13935dc07573ff360221bcb3fcfd8f44

Comment: I don't see a consumer binding for `test-input`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I have fixed the typo

Comment: I spent all day trying to get your docker.compose.yml to work on my Mac with no success. I gave up and used [Confluent's latest](https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html). I fixed your application.yml [here](https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/1a3d371056157c7cfc34528df5beb2e1) - you had some kafka-specifc properties in the wrong place. I confirmed the sync boolean is applied. I still don't see how adding that transaction expiration would cause the error when you are not using transactions (and I don't get the error).

Comment: Hi Gary, sorry for the late reply. After we reviewed the code with some workmates we realised the same thing as you pointed. The autocompletion tool in IntelliJ put the `sync` property inside the `transaction` field and it was wrong. After that, we used the `channelError` handler so we could get the exception. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Looks like this is fixed in the 2.4.0 broker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7190. Perhaps explains why I couldn't reproduce it (my broker is 2.4.1).

Comment: I think so... Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

probably you can also use the callback function to handle the exception, not sure about the springframework lib for kafka, if using kafka client, you can something like this:

```
producer.send(record, new Callback() {
        public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {
            if(e != null) {
               e.printStackTrace();

               if(e.getClass().equals(UnknownProducerIdException.class)) {
                   logger.info("UnknownProducerIdException caught");
                   while(--retry>=0) {
                       send(topic,partition,msg);
                   }
               }
            } else {
                logger.info("The offset of the record we just sent is: " + metadata.offset());
            }
        }
    });
```